# Get the type of value returned by a PHP file

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to assign as the value of a variable the return value of a `PHP` file only if this file returns an `array value`.

Let's say I have an `A.php` file with the following content:

File: `A.php`

```
<?php

return [
   'One' => 1,
   'Two' => 2
];
```

And I would like to assign in file `B.php`, the value returned by file `A.php` only if the value returned by file `A.php` is of type array.

What I have done is the following:

File: `B.php`

```
class B
{
    public function __construct() {

        $array = include 'path/to/B.php';

        ...
    }
}
```

in this way, I have in the `$array` variable the value returned by the `A.php` file, but, if in the `A.php` file, instead of returning an array, I write:

File: `A.php`

```
<?php

echo 'Hello World!';
```

when including it in the `B.php` file, the content of the file is evaluated and obviously produces an output with the content:

```
Hello World!
```

which I don't want.

My question is how to assign to the variable `$array` in the file `B.php` the value returned by the file `A.php` only if the value returned by `A.php` is of type array?.

**What i have seen:**

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.gettype.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype

Could you help me with my question? Is there an elegant way to do it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: A simple is_array() check in the constructor

Comment: You might want to throw an exception if return value ain't an array.

Comment: What do you want the variable to contain if not array?

Comment: @AbraCadaver just keep it null.

Comment: @nice_dev I want to evaluate the value returned by the A.php file before including it in the B.php file, do you think there is a more elegant way to do it without first having to include it and then evaluate the type of value it returns?

Comment: Is there any reason for not wanting to load it in B.php ? You have to include it somewhere if not B.php for you to work with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test it for an array:

```
if(!is_array($array = include 'path/to/B.php')) {
    $array = null;  // or whatever
}
```

But to take care of the instances where you may include a file that outputs something, just buffer output and clean it:

```
ob_start();
if(!is_array($array = include 'path/to/B.php')) {
    $array = null;  // or whatever
}
ob_end_clean();
```

If the file is not found `include` will return `false`.  If it is found and does not `return` something then it will return `1`.

Not recommended, but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.  You can extract the `return` and `eval` it:

```
//file A.php
$A = "return [
   'One' => 1,
   'Two' => 2
];";

//$A = file_get_contents('A.php');
    
preg_match('/return[^;]+;/', $A, $match);

if(isset($match[0])) {
    $array = eval($match[0]);
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is quite enlightening. This way you include the file first and then check the return type. But the same thing that I mentioned in my question happens, any expression is executed before, that is, any PHP code is executed before verifying the type of the returned value. With your example, if the B.php file contains the statement echo 'Hello World!', This will be executed regardless of the type of value returned by the file. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: `echo 'Hello World!` will be executed but with the `ob_` functions it buffers and clears the output buffer so you don't see this.  The possible issue is that if the included file defines a function that has been or will be defined later then it will generate a fatal error.  Not sure what else to do except read in the file and parse for `/return[^;]+;/` and `eval` it.

Comment: Coincidentally I was reading about the ```eval``` function. Thank you very much for your answer, really very enlightening.